# URL Query Parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, express

i'm facing a problem.

I'm using node and express. `Index.html` contains 2 inputs.

```
<form action="/profile" method="get">
    <input id="variable1" name="variable1"  type="text" placeholder="..."> //xxx
    Select : 
<select id="variable2" name="variable2">
    <optgroup label="y">
        <option value="variable">yyy</option>
    </select>
```

in `profile.js` I got:

```
router.get('/profile', function(req, res){

var var1 = req.params.variable1;
var var2 = req.params.variable2;

res.render('result');
}
```

Node renders `result.html`, but the URL i get is

```
https://localhost:3030/profile?variable1=xxx&variable2=yyy
```

> The question is how to get `https://localhost:3030/profile/xxx/yyy`
>   instead of the URL above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your route as: `/profile/:var1/:var2`

Now access them using req.params:

```
var var1 = req.params.var1;
var var2 = req.params.var2;
```

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

Though, it may be a bit dirty, you can try this as an alternative if you can't change the url where the form is submitted( though you can easily do that using javascript on form submission ):

```
router.get('/profile', function(req, res){

var var1 = req.query.variable1;
var var2 = req.query.variable2;
res.redirect('/profile/'+var1+'/'+var2);
}

router.get('/profile/:var1/:var2', function( req, res ){
var var1 = req.params.variable1;
var var2 = req.params.variable2;
res.render('result');
});
```

Comment: I've edited the question, because i can't handle it by myself :(

Comment: @BaSic Please check my updated answer if that helps.

Comment: Still nothing. It's probably something with index.html, because it's still https://localhost:3030/profile?variable1=xxx&variable2=yyy

Comment: Ouch wait. Something is going on

Comment: I have only added redirecting code, so first your browser will hit `localhost:3030/profile?variable1=xxx&variable2=yyy` as it is right now, but on that url, it will get redirected to `https://localhost:3030/profile/xxx/yyy`. Perhaps that's what you want. Though the cleaner way would be to send the params in a post query, if you do not want query parameters.